# Should we increase local port range limit on busy memcached servers

Tags: memcached

nixcraft has a tutorial on configuring memcached server([link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/setting-up-memcached-on-centos-rhel-fedora-linux.html)) at the end says:

> For busy memcached server you need to increase system file descriptor
>   and IP port limits

here is the code to do so:

```
# Increase system IP port limits
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 2000 65000
```

why should we do this? memcached is a server and it will respond to clients with its listening port which is 11211 by default. So we shouldn't be limited by local port range.(`net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range`) The only limit is file descriptors. local port range should be a limit for servers like `squid` which generate local traffic